# Setting the time step in Gazebo for ROS 2

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-plugin

I wish to change the time step in Gazebo for ROS 2. The `/gazebo/set_parameter` is shown by `ros2 service list` but upon calling, it shows `waiting for service to become available`.

I am running the following command:

```
ros2 service call /gazebo/setparameter rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters '{parameters: [{name: "max_time_step", value: {type: 3,double_value: 0.01}}]}'
```

1. Can we call `rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters` service like this?
2. What is the `type` for `double` data type.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Your command is missing `_` and using `setparameter` instead of `set_parameter`. Please confirm.